# Why stat and fstat return the st_size == 0?

Tags: c, linux, stat

I was testing a code from APUE, in chapter 14(*Advanced I/O*) of memory map file, the `fstat()` always return the `fdin`'s `st_size` as zero, and I tried `stat()` instead, and also get the same result. I list the code below(I have removed the *apue.h* dependencies):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define COPYINCR (1024*1024*1024) /* 1GB */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: %s <fromfile> <tofile>", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int fdin, fdout;
    if ((fdin = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        printf("can not open %s for reading", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fdout = open(argv[2] /* typo fix */, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)) < 0) {
        printf("can not open %s for writing", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    struct stat sbuf;
    if (fstat(fdin, &sbuf) < 0) { /* need size fo input file */
        printf("fstat error");
        exit(1);
    }


    // always zero, and cause truncate error (parameter error)
    printf("input_file size: %lld\n", (long long)sbuf.st_size); 

    if (ftruncate(fdout, sbuf.st_size) < 0) { /* set output file size */
        printf("ftruncate error");
        exit(1);
    }

    void *src, *dst;
    off_t fsz = 0;
    size_t copysz;
    while (fsz < sbuf.st_size) {
        if (sbuf.st_size - fsz > COPYINCR)
            copysz = COPYINCR;
        else
            copysz = sbuf.st_size - fsz;

        if (MAP_FAILED == (src = mmap(0, copysz, PROT_READ,
                        MAP_SHARED, fdin, fsz))) {
            printf("mmap error for input\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (MAP_FAILED == (dst = mmap(0, copysz,
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                            MAP_SHARED, fdout, fsz))) {
            printf("mmap error for output\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        memcpy(dst, src, copysz);
        munmap(src, copysz);
        munmap(dst, copysz);

        fsz += copysz;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And then I have tried the Python `os.stat`, it also get the zero result, why this happened? I have tried these and got the same result on Mac OS (Darwin kernel 13.4) and Ubuntu (kernel 3.13).

---

**UPDATE**:
Oh, there was a typo error, I should refer to `fdout` to `argv[2]`, and the `O_TRUNC` flag certainly make the `fdin` to zero. Should I close or delete this question?

The reason why Python's `os.stat()` also return `(stat.st_size == 0)` is that I passed the *same test file* (`argv[1]`) to test, and the file has been previously truncated to zero (I haven't check its size using `ls -lh` before passing to `os.stat()`), and certainly `os.stat()` return zero.

**Do not ask SO questions before you go to bed or in a rush.**

Comment: When you open `fdout`, the `O_TRUNC` truncates it. Since both `fdout` and `fdin` refer to the same file name (`argv[1]`), of course the size will be zero - you just truncated it.

Comment: +1 One of the official goals of stackoverflow is [rubber duck problem solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/), so don't be ashamed - you did right, great question.

Comment: Well done. You might very well post an answer to your own question.

Comment: I agree with Paulo Scardine and alk, and I think you should post an answer to your own question. I really like that you recognized *how* the typo happened, and why you missed it at first. I think documenting that is likely to help the next person who stumbles on this or something similar (we all make these kinds of bugs), and showing how to check/fix/avoid them is definitely useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the real problem is double `open` the same input file, and this does not cause any build or runtime error until the `ftruncate()`.

The first `open` get a read-only `fdin`, the second `open` create a new file (`fdout` and truncated) to copy from `fdin` via memory map, and the second open truncated the first file (`argv[1]`), and cleaned all its content. But the `fdin` **still working** with `fstat` (and certainly), this make me hard to find the reason.

The second part is I always use the same file for testing (generated via `dd`) and have not checking the size, so the `os.stat(/path/to/file)` and `stat(/path/to/file)` **also return** `st_size == 0`, this makes me believe that *this must be some os-level-prolicy defined the behaviour, and I rushed to Mac OS (using the same typo code), and got the same result (they really consistent on POSIX level, event the bug!), and at last, I came to SO for help*.